# jQuery UI DatePicker - Update global events array with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a jQuery UI DatePicker highlighting events and event info when clicked. The events are set in an static (hard coded) array formatted like this:

```
var events = [ 
    { Title: "Event 1", Date: new Date("11/15/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Event 2", Date: new Date("11/15/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Event 3", Date: new Date("11/25/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Event 4", Date: new Date("11/30/2013") }
];
```

This works well but the events array needs to be updated on DatePicker 'onChangeMonthYear' so I have added an ajax call each time selecting a new month but have some trouble..

**Question: How-to update the global events array with the return from ajax call?**

This is what I have tried so far:
PHP

```
$items = array();
foreach ($events as $event) {
$items[]= array('Title' => $event['SUMMARY'],'Date' => gmdate("m/d/Y",$event['DTSTART']));
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

JS

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'GET',
async : false,
data: {start : firstDay, end : lastDay},
url: "ajax/getCalendarItems.php",
success: function(data){
    events = data;
}
});
```

Result:

```
console.log(data)
[{"Title":"New event 1","Date":"12\/20\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 2","Date":"12\/20\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 3","Date":"12\/23\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 4","Date":"12\/30\/2013"}]

TypeError: '[{"Title":"New event 1","Date":"12\/20\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 2","Date":"12\/20\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 3","Date":"12\/23\/2013"},{"Title":"New event 4","Date":"12\/30\/2013"}]' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 't-1 in e')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting

```
        dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

in you ajax call's parameters? It should automatically decode the json data you passed from PHP server.

Because it seems like your 'data' parameter is still JSON.

Let me know! :)

Comment: I didn't understand.. was my answer helpful or just userless? :)

Comment: helpful :) tried to post a new answer but have not the reputation points needed...

Comment: anyway, no errors with your answer but events are not highlighted in calendar so there might be something with the date comparison.. there are some differences in the initial array date vs the date fetched in ajax php call, new Date etc

Comment: Ok, found error in comparison between returned object date and the dates in DatePicker... Thats why they are not highlighted. 12/23/2013===1388703600000

Comment: Understood.. Happy to ear that from you ;) Could you give the +1 to my answer? Obviously not the mark as correct 'cause you completed the work by yourself..

Comment: All working! Thanks for helping me out with the dataType and contentType. The final thing was to convert date in json object to milliseconds.